# Get Age from DOB in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to show my members age in profile page. in php file i just added this code to show users birth day:

```
$data = $db->super_query( "SELECT dob FROM dle_users" );
$tpl->set("{bdate}", $data['dob']);
```

and in profile page i have this result:

```
1364-07-09
```

*Its a Persian's date: yyyy-mm-dd*

now i need to show members age, i searched in google and this site, i found some answers and tips, but in wont work for me! i don't know why.

how i can show age? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURRENT_DATE) AS age FROM dle_users
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MySQL (if that is what you're using) date functions, they'll do a whole host of converting for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Maybe `DATEDIFF( NOW(), dob )` or some such malarkey, but that would return the difference in days, or `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, NOW(), dob )` for months

Comment: thanks but its too hard for me to learn too much sql in 1 hour :D could u please do me a favor and helping me more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dob, NOW()) AS difference from dle_users;
```

This will give you the difference in date which you can convert to various formats using PHP

```
date("m/d/y g:i (A)", $DB_Date_Field);
```

Also you can directly use the TIMESTAMPDIFF as:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) as difference from dle_users;
```

Read 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety:

```
select year(now()) - year(dob) - if(dayofyear(now()) < dayofyear(dob), 1, 0) from dle_users
```